# Can a Java program access a specific port on a Guacamole connection?

Tags: java, linux, apache, lxd, guacamole

Can I use the Apache Guacamole API to allow a Java program to access a specific port on a Guacamole server's connection? When I say connection, I mean a machine that the Guacamole server is connected to - a machine that would show up in the Guacamole web interface.

**Background:**
I set up an Ubuntu virtual machine as a local Guacamole server/client. The virtual machine also runs a series of centOS (LXD) containers, each with a respective IP address. Outside of the virtual machine, on the host machine on the same network, I am able to access the Guacamole web interface via a web browser and SSH into the centOS containers just fine.

Let's say I have a Java program on my host machine that needs to communicate with one of those centOS containers. Is it possible to use the Guacamole API to allow the Java program on the host machine to programmatically access a specific port on one of the Guacamole connections/centOS containers?

If so, how would I go about doing that? I'd appreciate any specific examples or documentation related to this. If there's a better way to go about this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also struggling with the same issue. If you have finished it, can you guide me?